# React onClick method sets variable to true but only for a second when the page reloads - how to make changes permanent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a React page which shows an input field and a submit button inside a form. When users click submit, whatever is inside the input field is displayed correctly on the form. However, this seems to only last a second until the React page reloads and the page reverts back to what it was before. How do I get around this? I am currently using a simple boolean which goes to true when the user clicks 'submit' but since it is set to 'false' at the top of the page, I believe this is what is causing the issues when the page reloads.

```
class App extends Component {
centreValue = false
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {value : "story"}
}
onChange = (e) => {
    this.centreValue = true
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    let dag = {
        centreField : e.target.value
    }
    if (dag.centreField != undefined){
        this.centreValue = dag.centreField

    }

}

render() {
    const { fname} = this.state;
    let centreInput;
    let unfilledInputText = 'Enter sentence here'
    if (this.centreValue){
        centreInput = <input type="text" name="centreField" value={this.centreValue}
        />;
    }
    else {
        centreInput = <input type="text" name="centreField" value={unfilledInputText}/>
    }
    return (

        <table>
                <th>
                    <form >
                        {centreInput}
                                <input type="submit" value="Submit" onMouseUp={this.onChange}/>
                    </form>
                </th>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}
```

}

export default App;

Comment: Changes won't persist on page reload unless you use something like `localStorage` / `sessionStorage` / `cookies`

Answer (score 2):

You should add e.preventDefault();

```
onChange = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
this.centreValue = true
this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
let dag = {
    centreField : e.target.value
}
if (dag.centreField != undefined){
    this.centreValue = dag.centreField

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button refreshes the page since it's a normal form. Do e.preventDefault() in the beginning of your function. Your onChange should also be on the textfield itself. Also, I would recommend using Formik as it handles most of this for you (and more) in React.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. I've have already tried adding e.preventDefault() to the beggining of th onChange = (e) function and it hasnt worked sadly. Would you be able to show how I would do this using Formik as its all new to me?